# Edge browser displays popup when typing forward slash in input field

Tags: html, browser, microsoft-edge

I'm working on an edge extension that includes an input field where users can enter a delimiter character to serve as a 'folder' delimiter for branch names in gitlab (would group branches based on the folder name). However, when the user types a forward slash (/) as the first character in the input field, Edge displays a popup that says "Start typing to search" and also shows a "Manage personal info" button. This behavior would be annoying for the user.

Is there any way to disable this Edge browser behavior when typing a forward slash as the first character in an input field?

This is the html for the extension, if it helps:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>GitLab Folders</title>
    <style>
        body {
            width: 200px;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
        form {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            margin: 20px 0;
        }
        h1 {
            margin-top: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        label {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            font-size: 13px;
        }
        .centered {
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
        }
        .annotation {
            font-size: 14px;
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }
        input[type="text"] {
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 16px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
            width: 186px;
        }
        button[type="submit"] {
            padding: 8px 12px;
            font-size: 16px;
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 4px;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 150px;
            margin-top: 5px;
        }
        button[type="submit"]:hover {
            background-color: #3e8e41;
        }
        button[disabled] {
            background-color: gray;
            color: white;
            pointer-events: none;
        }

        button[disabled]:hover {
            background-color: gray;
            color: white;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Gitlab folder structure</h1>
    <form>
        <label for="input-field">Enter characters to serve as folder name delimiters (default is '/'): </label>
        <div>
            <span id="annotation" class="annotation">Current delimiter(s): /</span>
        </div>
        <input class="centered" type="text" id="input-field" name="input-field" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Only delimiters, ex: '/\-'">
        <button class="centered" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a screenshot showing the edge popup on the extensions' popup:
[popup on typing '/' as first char](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIMkj.png)

I've tried various solutions including setting the autocomplete attribute to "off", using the keydown event listener to intercept the forward slash key press, and adding the autofocus attribute to the input field. None of these solutions have worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `aria-autocomplete="both"` into `<input>` to disable this popup. For more information, you can read [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-autocomplete).

Comment: Your suggestion does solve my problem. However, I still do not get it. Citing from the documentation:

"aria-autocomplete="both" an input to offer both models at the same time. When a user is providing input, an element containing a collection of values that could complete the provided input may be displayed. If displayed, one value in the collection is automatically selected, and the text needed to complete the automatically selected value appears after the caret in the input"

It says something might still be displayed. Nowhere does it say that will stop the popup. Am I missing smth?